# Google Sheets Validation Lists

Tags: javascript, excel, google-sheets-api

After some help on a bit of code to apply validations to cells.

Scenario: - I have a matrix list of products in column A and Areas in row 1
If a product can be in that area then the intersect field has a x. (So if I have Product in A20 and Area D1 then cell D20 would have an x)

I need to apply a data validation to a range based on each product (Column A) and add the area name where there is an x.

I could do this in normal excel but my javascript is very limited.

(bit more info if needed)

I have a Template Page - ironically called template. I want to be able to click a button, which will then grab all products (From a tab called Products), it will then copy the template page, call it whatever the product is called and then apply in column B (B2 onwards) the data validation as per above)

(i have a bit of code that creates the tabs)

Any help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: You might want to check [Extending Google Sheets - Data validation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#data_validation). Apps Script lets you access existing data-validation rules in Google Sheets or create new rules. In this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJUVrhmv3A8) provided by Google, Kalyan Reddy gives an overview of the data validation functionality in Apps Script. It will help you learn the basics on how data validation works in Google Sheets, how to create your own validation rules programmatically. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Watched the video and makes more sense now.